# Golang return multiple values memory representation

Tags: go

When a function returns multiple values in go, what's the memory representation of those `multiple values` when returned?

Comment: What do you mean by 'memory representation'?

Comment: @GrzegorzŻur this is actually a good question, asking about how are multiple values represented in memory - stored in registers, or on stack, or allocate memory on heap,...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What it sounds like you're looking for is the stack frame design of Go. I'm not going into the details here, but you may find it helpful to read [about it here](https://blog.cloudflare.com/how-stacks-are-handled-in-go/).

In general the compiler can place multiple returns on the out space for the function call. Think an array as a result. The compiler then knows how to access the space on the stack for the subsequent caller.